# Woocommerce add Product Tab with Checkbox to add function to add a second add to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need some of your Help, mamy thanks for your efforts.!

My problem is, that a plugin which is installed replaces the standard add to cart on Product page. I don't want to Change it and i need to add an second Add to cart below it. The Case is, that a other plugin for free prosuct samples needs the regular Add to carry Button.

When i Add the global Script it works well, but on all products.

```
Add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart, 1 );
```

I want this on the product Tab where i can Turn IT on and off with a checkbox for the selected product.

My Code so far, but it doesn't do anything. The checkbox works & checkbox saving also. But the snippet is not doing the command for the Adding to cart on meta start of Product frontend Page.

```
// Add checkbox field to the Product tab in the admin area

function add_checkbox_to_product_tab() {

    // Add checkbox field to the General tab

    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array(

        'id' => 'add_to_cart_checkbox',

        'label' => 'Warenkorb Hinzufügen',

                'desc_tip'       => false, // true or false, show description directly or as tooltip

        'description' => 'ja'

    ) );

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_checkbox_to_product_tab' );

 

// Save checkbox field value

function save_checkbox_value( $product ) {

    $checkbox = isset( $_POST['add_to_cart_checkbox'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';

    $product->update_meta_data( 'add_to_cart_checkbox', $checkbox );

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_checkbox_value' );

 

// Add action when checkbox is selected with 'yes'

function add_action_when_checkbox_selected( $product_id ) {

    $checkbox_value = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_add_to_cart_checkbox', true );

    if ( $checkbox_value == 'yes' ) {

        do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start' );

        do_action( 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart' );

    }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 'add_action_when_checkbox_selected',  1 );
```

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you would like to hide the default "Add to Cart" button and the custom "Add to Cart" button when the checkbox value is set to "no". On the other hand, if the checkbox value is set to "yes", you would like to display the default "Add to Cart" button. Is that correct?

Comment: Many thanks for your Response @Bhautik. I want to add a second Add to cart Button on the Product Front Page. I want to Control It in the product Tab in the Backend. Via the checkbox If it is on yes the snippet should Add a second Add to cart Button on the position woocommerce_product_meta_start. If the Checkbox Is on no, then there ist nothing to do for the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `woocommerce_product_meta_start` hook. check the below code.

```
// Add a checkbox field to the Product tab in the admin area
function add_checkbox_to_product_tab() {
    // Add checkbox field to the General tab
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array(
        'id' => 'add_to_cart_checkbox',
        'label' => 'Warenkorb Hinzufügen',
        'desc_tip' => false,
        'description' => 'ja'
    ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_checkbox_to_product_tab' );

// Save checkbox field value
function save_checkbox_value( $product ) {
    $checkbox = isset( $_POST['add_to_cart_checkbox'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    $product->update_meta_data( 'add_to_cart_checkbox', $checkbox );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_checkbox_value' );

// Remove standard "Add to Cart" button if checkbox value is 'no'
function add_custom_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;
    $checkbox_value = $product->get_meta( 'add_to_cart_checkbox' );
    if ( $checkbox_value == 'yes' ) {
        // Add your custom "Add to Cart" button code here
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="button alt">Custom Add to Cart</a>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start', 'add_custom_add_to_cart_button', 40 );
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

Comment: I followed your instruction, mamy thanks. Like I've already wrote, I really appreciate your Help, but my problem ist Not solved yet

Comment: it's required additional debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it, tested and works well. If someone will need it in Future:

```
// Add checkbox in the Product settings
function add_custom_product_checkbox() {
    global $post;
    $checked = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_checkbox', true);
    ?>
    <div class="options_group">
        <p class="form-field">
            <label for="checkbox"><?php _e( 'Your description', 'textdomain' ); ?></label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked( $checked, '1' ); ?> />
        </p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_custom_product_checkbox' );

// Save the value of the checkbox
function save_custom_product_checkbox( $post_id ) {
    $checkbox = isset( $_POST['checkbox'] ) ? '1' : '0';
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_checkbox', $checkbox );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_product_checkbox' );

// function to add a Second add to cart on meta start
trigger_woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart() {
    $checked = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_checkbox', true );
    if ( $checked === '1' ) {
        do_action( 'woocommerce_meta_start' );
        woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart();
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'trigger_woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 15 );
```